# iPhone screenshot

Tags: iphone, screenshot

How can I create a iPhone screenshot? When I open Xcode I go to Window>Organizer but there is no Devices tab visible. I have a jail-braken phone with OS 3.1.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your phone, hold the home button and press the sleep button. A screenshot will be taken and saved to your camera roll.

Your other problem might be due to lack of development profile, certificates, etc. but there isn't enough information in the question to help you with that...

Answer (score 0):

Take screen shot from your iphone by holding home button and sleep button .screen shot is saved in your camera roll.

If you face any problem and device is not coming on organizer. you can import screenshots by using preview application. Preview -->Files -->Import from "your device name"